# How to get new selected and old values after user selected option from dropdown list box?

Tags: angularjs

I have angularjs dropdown list box:

```
    <select class="form-control"
            ng-model="editor.frequency"
            ng-options="item as item.Name for item in editor.frequencies"
            ng-change="editor.editFrequencyManual = false;">
   </select>
```

After user click on option in dropdown list box I need to get clicked(selected) value and the old value(before selection).

Any idea how can I get this two values?Is there event function that I sholud use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could watch the changes on your model:

```
$scope.$watch('editor', function(newValue, oldValue){
    //
});
```

Or you could modify `ng-change` so that it passes old and new values as parameters:

```
    <select class="form-control"
            ng-model="editor.frequency"
            ng-options="item as item.Name for item in editor.frequencies"
            ng-change="changed(editor.frequency, {{editor.frequency}}); editor.editFrequencyManual = false;">
   </select>
```

Of course, you should move `editor.editFrequencyManual = false;` into the change function.

```js
function myController($scope) {
  $scope.myModel = {};
  $scope.doThis = function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log("New value: " + newValue);
    console.log("Old value: " + oldValue);
  }
}

angular.module('myApp', []);
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller('myController', myController);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
      <select ng-model="myModel" ng-change="doThis(myModel, '{{myModel}}');">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.I feel a little bit silly to ask you about it but, any way what is meaning of this '{{editor.frequency}}'. I mean when parameter passed in curly brackets?

Comment: @Michael It will interpolate the value inside the html element when it's created so you get a static string to pass to the function.

Comment: @Michael You don't need the single quotes actually since the value is already interpolated when it's passed to the function. I added a snippet to demonstrate.