# Capture arrow key event in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a web page and in that page i have a drop down list. I want value of selected item in that drop down list by using arrow key in angular js.

Comment: Try [`ngChange`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971161/how-to-get-new-selected-and-old-values-after-user-selected-option-from-dropdown/38971525#38971525 Run the snippet, tab to focus the select element and move the arrow keys. It will log the values.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help

Answer (score 0):

Usually I preferred to use the index of the item as the value of `ng-model` as it is automatically bind to controller, I add the index as an attribute for each item in the collection with a `map()` function.

```
$scope.selectOptions = myCollection.map(function(item, index){
    var obj = item;
    item.idx = index;
    return obj;
});
```

Then in my `select` element

```
<select name="sel_item"                         
    ng-model="selectedIdx"
    ng-options="option.idx as option.label for option in selectOptions">
</select>
```

I use this way only when I can be sure that `myCollection` not gonna change (immutable). Now from the controller I can access easily each item in `myCollection[selectedIdx]`